# What is this code doing? I'm unsure of this $ role and new to the Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code was just thrown at me to try and force my width to fit in all broswers instead of taking the longest string and making the width that size which is the state its in now. I'm new to all of this and unsure if I'm understanding it right. Please help any advice will be greatly appreciated.. Thanks

```
if($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) < 8)
{
    var relevantDropdowns = $('select[name*="codeValue"]');
    relevantDropdowns.mousedown(function()
    {
        if($(this).css('width')!== 'auto');
        {
            $(this).css('width', 'auto');
            $(this).css('position', 'absolute');
        }
    });

    relevantDropdowns.blur(function()
    {
        $(this).css('width', '100px');
        $(this).css('position', '');
    });

    relevantDropdowns.change(function()
    {
        $(this).css('width', '100px');
        $(this).css('position', '');
    });
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What exactly do you need help with?

Comment: if you really just want to know what the $ is doing, read this: http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works

Comment: jQuery's [`.browser`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/) is deprecated. This means that it can, and *will*, stop working without warning in the near future. If you're not using a particular old-release of jQuery, please change your `if` to attempt feature detection, or an alternative approach.

Comment: It sounds like they're a jQuery newbie and want to know what the `$` means in this code.

Comment: I guess what is the $ role because I think that's what is throwing me off in understanding the code

Answer (score 4):

`$` is the alias for `jQuery`, the object that implements the totality of jQuery functionality. It can be used in several ways:

- as a plain object, to access its properties (as in `$.browser.msie`)
- as a function accepting a string (or an element, or an array of elements, or a jQuery collection), which selects elements from the DOM and wraps them, returning a jQuery collection (as in `$(select[name*="codeValue"]')`, to select by string, or in `$(this)`, to wrap a primitive element)
- as a function accepting a function, as an alias to `$.ready()`

The second one is the most common to jQuery, and is used to access elements from the document. The returned jQuery collection then implements a bunch of jQuery methods, which usually return the same collection, so they can be chained.

Answer (score 1):

This is code that uses the jQuery library.  In jQuery, the `$` symbol is used as both a function and an object.  So `$.browser.msie` is a property value.  And `$(this)` is a function call where it calls the `$` function and passes it `this` as an argument.

In jQuery, passing a DOM element to the `$` function returns a jQuery object which you can then call a bunch of jQuery methods on.

For example:

```
$(this).css('width')
```

gets the CSS width of an object (internally it uses getComputedStyle).

```
$(this).css('width', 'auto');
```

sets the CSS width of an object to 'auto'.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation that makes more sense now